# Kotlin - Multi platform feature

Tags: javascript, jvm, kotlin, multiplatform

I'm currently playing around with Kotlin multi platform feature and have a minor problem. When I start gradle multi-platform project in Intellij and use keywords 'actual' and 'expect', they are underlined in red and show message "The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly"

How can I explicitly enable multi platform feature?
Thanks

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik doesn't work, throws message "Could not find method multiplatform() for arguments [enable] on object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.ExperimentalExtension."

Comment: It was a shot in the dark, anyway, by analogy to enabling experimental coroutines.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know, I saw it too, it would probably make the most sense

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found an answer. In Intellij in *Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Kotlin Compiler* append to *Additional command line parameters:* field command *-Xmulti-platform*.

[image]

Comment: The IDE should have added it automatically when you create a multiplatform project... perhaps raise an issue at YouTrack?

Comment: This helped me, but I also had to change "use project settings" to true. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852066/kotlin-multi-platform-feature

Comment: on AS I don't have this option, I'd add the option by gradle.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Gradle you can enable the multi-platform feature by adding `-Xmulti-platform` flag to compiler arguments in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xmulti-platform"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This warning can be suppressed by adding the below line to `gradle.properties` file

```
kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true
```

Here the complete project.properies file for reference

```
kotlin.code.style=official
xcodeproj=./iosApp
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true
kotlin.native.enableDependencyPropagation=false
kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true
```