# How to fix 'The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly' warning in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Whenever I write an `expect` function in IntelliJ IDEA, I get the following warning:
`The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly`

Where can enable this feature? I already searched the settings and didn't find a way to disable that warning.

Compilation with gradle works fine.

Comment: I already looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852066/kotlin-multi-platform-feature

Comment: maybe this can help :- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43284

Comment: Thanks, seems I have to wait for the next IntelliJ Release

Answer (score 2):

A work around that could work for you is here:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18408#focus=Comments-27-5220925.0-0

You can find the full discussion here:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18408

In short, the issue is related to the ability of kotlin multiplatform to use native libraries in the hierarchical structure:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-share-on-platforms.html#use-native-libraries-in-the-hierarchical-structure

There are some conflicts between native libraries and the common code features such as expect keyword.