# expect and actual fun errors - The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

This is what my project shows:

[image: The project of mine]

Unlike mine, the sample project I downloaded from Github looks like this:
[image: Sample Project]

I know those red things won't affect my project build, but It's kinda sick for me seeing those red things. Any solution for removing them? (I'm using Android Studio)

**EDIT**: This message appeared when I hover into the red thing:

[image]

Comment: When you hover over the red squiggles, what is the error message?

Comment: *I know those red things won't affect my project build* - do you mean you tried and successfully built the project via command line?

Comment: Maybe you have a gradle sync issue

Comment: @Joffrey of course, the application runs smoothly when I built the project via command line

Comment: @isthemartin My gradle is fine I think

Comment: @RakaM.A have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725327/how-to-fix-the-feature-multi-platform-projects-is-experimental-and-should-be

Comment: @isthemartin I checked the post, but none of them solve my problem